# CSS Fit image into container

Tags: css, image

Is there a css-way to fit any image into a container? (saving proportions)

If image is smaller than conteiner, `min-width/-height` do the job. If image is bigger, then `max-width/-height`.

So what is the way to fit any smaller/bigger image? Obviously it is not both min/max.

Should work in IE11

```
<div style='width:20vh; height:20vh; text-align:center'>
    <img style='width:auto; height:auto; max-width:100%; max-height:100%; display:inline' src='...' />
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried

Comment: What does `fit` mean? Do you want the image to stretch to the farthrest edge of the container so that the container is fully filled, which crops the image? Or do you want the image to stretch to the nearest edge, so the image is at maximim size without being stretched?

Comment: Fit into and save proportions. I understand what that means. Nearest edge

Comment: @ituy No, it's not clear what you intend. Fit could mean `cover` or `contain`

Comment: Sorry In my previous comment I typed the last word `stretched`, but I wanted to type `cropped`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your image as background in your container using css

Then set back ground size 100% as the following:

```
<div style="background-image: url("yourImgSrc");background-size: 100% 100%;">
```

Answer (score 3):

If background image is acceptable then use background-size: contain; with background-position: center; to have keep centered and save aspect ratio too. See a snippet below. It works on IE11 too.

```css
.image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563927648995-79a6ffffc028?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```